# How can I set up my model with ImageMagick in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'd like to insert arguement as text onto the image file that user uploads.
With the code below, It doesn't work. It just saves image without any effect.
I'm using the gem called 'papaerclip' for uploading.

**comment.rb**

```
#paperclip
has_attached_file :comment_icon,
    :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100>",
    :small  => "400x400>" }, 
    :convert_options => {
    :all => " -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon' -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon'" }
```

How can I insert text to the bottom of images like this example?
How **comment.rb** should be written?

**ImageMagick code**

```
  convert dragon.gif -gravity south \
          -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon' \
          -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon' \
          anno_outline.jpg
```

Comment: Is Paperclip (or ImageMagick) throwing any exceptions?

Comment: seems like a bug, did you tried upgrade to latest version of paperclip?

Comment: It doesn' say anything in log. It's almost looking working fine.

Comment: my paperclip version is 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't like the single quotes you have in your convert_options.  Try using:

```
' -gravity south -stroke "#000C" -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 "Faerie Dragon" -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 "Faerie Dragon"'
```

instead.  I am using Paperclip 3.2.0 and was able to get it to apply the text by changing the quotes.

Here is my image attribute:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
:styles => {:large => "300x300", :medium => "140x140>", :thumb => "100x100>", :tiny => "50x50" },
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazons3.yml",
:path => "avatars/:id/:style_:filename",
:convert_options => {
:all => ' -gravity south -stroke "#000C" -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 "Faerie Dragon" -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 "Faerie Dragon"' }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still the same. It won't add any effect:(

Comment: Are you able to upgrade your version of paperclip at all?  When I used your original string with the single quotes I saw an exception in the log: Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for ...

Comment: I updated paperclip to 3.4 and replaced quote part with your code but it still wont add text to image. Do I need to have rmagick gem? or just ImageMagick?

Comment: I am just using imagemagick.  Is the resize specified in styles being applied?

Comment: I also noticed the "-gravity south" parameters weren't in your convert_options string, maybe that is why you aren't seeing the text applied.

Comment: No problem, glad we figured it out!

Comment: Thanks! One problem. it won't apply to the image file which is stored in original dir. what if you'd like to apply effects to all the types of sized images?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22143/discussion-between-jeff-steil-and-foo)